# Multithreaded MKL and Eigen

Tags: multithreading, eigen, armadillo, intel-mkl, accelerate-framework

I need to use a parallel linear algebra **on OSX** and **as painlessly as possible** (i.e., *at most* I can use HomeBrew with my colleagues) factorization library due to the number of DOFs I have in my problems.

I've tried Armadillo, it supports sparse algebra which is what I need, I can link with the `Accelerate` framework, but it just *solves* linear problems, it doesn't support factorization AFAIK.

Next, MKL, but nothing I can do seems to trigger threading, even with TBB:

```
tbb::task_scheduler_init scheduler(4);
mkl_set_dynamic(true);
mkl_set_num_threads(4);
mkl_set_num_threads_local(4);
```

Eigen could be cool, but it seems that, like MKL, it won't run in parallel.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Which compiler do you use? osx clang does not support openmp, which is required by multi-thread Eigen and may be required by multi-thread MKL.

Comment: Of course I use clang, but MKL says that TBB can be used instead of OpenMP. But I don't see any multiple threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSX clang does not support openmp, which is required by multi-thread Eigen and MKL.

According to [Intel® Math Kernel Library Link Line Advisor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor), MKL does not support TBB threading with clang.

But it seems to support Intel OpenMP library with the extra link option `-liomp5`. You could try if it works. If not, you may have to use another compiler such as gcc. You could find it in HomeBrew.